# Refer to previous row in data.table in R, with a condition

Tags: r, data.table

i have a new problem with this data. Because my full data has the form like this

```
a=data.table(A=c(1:10),B=c(1,2,0,2,0,0,3,4,0,2),C=c(2,3,1,4,5,3,6,7,2,2),D=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)) 


#     A B C D  
# 1:  1 1 2 1  
# 2:  2 2 3 1  
# 3:  3 0 1 1  
# 4:  4 2 4 1  
# 5:  5 0 5 1  
# 6:  6 0 3 2  
# 7:  7 3 6 2  
# 8:  8 4 7 2  
# 9:  9 0 2 2  
#10: 10 2 2 2
```

Now, I want to create a new column, which calculates the number of values of A multiple with B/C of the closet previous row, as long as B is not 0. For example, in line 2, I can calculate D=2*(1/2). However, in line 4, it has to be 4*(2/3), it can not be 4*(0/1).
I use

```
a[, D:= {i1 <- (NA^!B)
list( A*shift(na.locf(i1*B))/shift(na.locf(i1*C)))},by=d]
```

as Akrun recommended yesterday. It does not work when i calculate it by group.the result is like this

```
    A B C d        D
# 1:  1 1 2 1       NA
# 2:  2 2 3 1 1.000000
# 3:  3 0 1 1 2.000000
# 4:  4 2 4 1 2.666667
# 5:  5 0 5 1 2.500000
# 6:  6 0 3 2       NA
# 7:  7 3 6 2 3.500000
# 8:  8 4 7 2 4.571429
# 9:  9 0 2 2 5.142857
# 10: 10 2 2 2       NA
```

Anyone knows what is the problem here? The error is longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length.

Comment: What would be the output for the first element of D?

Comment: The output for the first element of D would be NA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can replace the elements in 'B', 'C' that corresponds to '0' value in 'B' as NA.  Use `na.locf` from `zoo` to replace those NA values with the previous non-NA elements, `shift` the elements (by default, it gives a `lag` of 1), divide the modified columns 'B' with 'C' and then multiply by 'A'.  Assign (`:=`) the output to a new column 'D'.

```
 library(zoo)
 a[B==0, c('B', 'C'):=list(NA, NA)]
 a[, c('B', 'C'):= na.locf(.SD), .SDcols=B:C]
 a[,  D:= {tmp <- shift(.SD[, 2:3, with=FALSE])
           A*(tmp[[1]]/tmp[[2]])}]
```

---

Or we can make it compact.  We get a logical vector (`!B`) that checks for '0' elements in 'B', convert that to a vector of 1s and NA (`NA^`), multiply with columns 'B' and 'C' so that the 1s are replaced by the corresponding elements in those columns whereas NA remains as such.  Do the `na.locf` (as before), `shift` and then do the multiplication/division.

```
a[, D:= {i1 <- (NA^!B)
   list( A*shift(na.locf(i1*B))/shift(na.locf(i1*C)))}]
```

Or instead of calling `shift/na.locf` two times

```
a[,  D:= {i1 <- (NA^!B)
      tmp <- shift(na.locf(i1*.SD))
      a[['A']]*(tmp[[1]]/tmp[[2]])}, .SDcols=B:C]
```

Comment: Thanks. You really solve my problems. It is really compact too.

Comment: Hi, @akrun, could you please take a look?

Comment: @ThanhQuang  YOu may need `...na.locf(i1*B), na.rm=FALSE)/shift(na.locf(i1*C, na.rm=FALSE)...`

Comment: Thanks. everything is solved now. can't thank you enough

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a rolling join:

```
a[, row := .I]
a[, B/C, by=row][V1 != 0][a, A*shift(V1), on="row", roll=TRUE]
# [1]       NA 1.000000 2.000000 2.666667 2.500000 3.000000 3.500000 4.000000
# [9] 5.142857 5.714286
```